# C sharp Windows media player ActiveX does not go to a specific time when the video is paused

Tags: c#, activex, windows-media-player, wmp

I have added a button to allow the user to jump one second forward everytime it is clicked.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition += 1;
    }
```

so this is working when the video is playing, if I pause the video and click the button i can see that the timer is going one second forward but the video stay in the same frame.

Can you please advice how to do that ?

I have been looking for some solution to move one frame forward using this code:

```
((IWMPControls2)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols).step(1);
```

but I got an error message when I using IWMPControls2, I understand it's an interface but does it need a reference ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any Answer ? please help

Answer (score -1):

You should add a `using WMPLib;` statement

Comment: It would be better if you addes a note to say why.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide the original poster (OP) some additional information. You should include why the `using WMPLib;` is required.